# Running a JAR file created by Leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen, uberjar

I have the following code in the file project.clj:

```
(defproject pinger "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A website availability tester"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :main pinger.core)

(ns pinger.core
  (:import (java.net URL HttpURLConnection))
  (:gen-class))

(defn response-code [address]
  (let [conn ^HttpURLConnection (.openConnection (URL. address))
    code (.getResponseCode conn)]
    (when (< code 400)
      (-> conn .getInputStream .close))
    code))

(defn available? [address]
  (= 200 (response-code address)))

(defn -main []
  (let [addresses '("http://google.com"
            "http://amazon.com"
            "http://google.com/badurl")]
    (while true
      (doseq [address addresses]
    (println (available? address)))
      (Thread/sleep (* 1000 60)))))
```

I create an uberjar:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\ProgrammingClojure\code\src
\pinger>lein uberjar
Cleaning up.
Copying 1 file to C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\Programmi
ngClojure\code\src\pinger\lib
Warning: *classpath* not declared dynamic and thus is not dynamically rebindable
, but its name suggests otherwise. Please either indicate ^:dynamic *classpath*
or change the name.
Copying 1 file to C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\Programmi
ngClojure\code\src\pinger\lib
Created C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\ProgrammingClojure\
code\src\pinger/pinger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including pinger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Including clojure-1.3.0.jar
Created C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\ProgrammingClojure\
code\src\pinger/pinger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
```

I then try to run that uberjar and get the following error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\vreinpa\My Documents\Books\ProgrammingClojure\code\src
\pinger>java -jar pinger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: pinger/core
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pinger.core
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: pinger.core. Program will exit.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

As I said [in response to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020243/defproject-compiler-exception), the project.clj file is not the place to put source code - project.clj is loaded by leiningen to set up your project configuration and putting arbitrary code there is not guaranteed to work *at all*, and will certainly mess up the loading of namespaces you defined in there. follow the [conventions for source libs](http://clojure.org/libs) and put the files under the src directory in your project tree.

Comment: It's an example from a "Programming Clojure" book, which implicitly tells to put the code in `project.clj`. I guess, the authors didn't try too hard when writing this chapter.

Answer (score 0):

`$ lein new pinger`
`$ cd pinger`
`$ lein deps`

pinger/project.clj

```
(defproject pinger "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "A website availability tester"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]
  :main pinger.core)
```

pinger/src/pinger/core.clj

```
(ns pinger.core
  (:import (java.net URL HttpURLConnection))
  (:gen-class))

(defn response-code [address]
  (let [conn ^HttpURLConnection (.openConnection (URL. address))
    code (.getResponseCode conn)]
    (when (< code 400)
      (-> conn .getInputStream .close))
    code))

(defn available? [address]
  (= 200 (response-code address)))

(defn -main []
  (let 
    [addresses
      '("http://google.com"
        "http://amazon.com"
        "http://google.com/badurl")]
  (while true
    (doseq [address addresses]
      (println (available? address)))
    (Thread/sleep (* 1000 60)))))
```

`$ cd pinger`
`$ lein uberjar`

absolute path
`$ java -jar /vagrant/MyClojure/pinger/target/pinger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`

or

relative path from project.clj
`$ java -jar ./target/pinger-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar`